# How to compress repetitive information when uploading mesh data?

Tags: opengl, geometry-shader

I want to avoid sending repetitive information when drawing a mesh.

If I use a single point for each face and two vectors as additional attributes that represent the travel of each vertex, I can use that information in a Geometry Shader to produce the normal and the two points followed by any additional attributes for that face.

Is the computation cost worth the saved data needing to be transferred? Or is there a better way to optimize the pipeline for sending over a mesh to draw?

Edit:
In particular this is a case where the mesh has attributes unique to the face and not the vertex, so if it were done the regular way each vertex would be multiplied by the number of faces used by it.

Comment: "Is the computation cost worth the saved data?" That may depend on the nature of your meshes and your target hardware. What does your profiling tell you when you test this? Are you sure that the mesh upload (which usually happens once when you load a new mesh, not every frame), is really the bottleneck in your renderer that needs optimizing?

Comment: Never assume something is a bottleneck unless the profiler tells you it is. I've made that mistake a lot myself... hunted for a framerate drop due to sounds playing for several days when it was really the text renderer chugging. It happened I added both the sound and changing the score readout at the same time, and just assumed the sound was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let's assume you're working with an endless grid of 2-triangle quads, with normals/texture coordinates shared at each vertex. This is similar to what you'd use for a terrain mesh, and character meshes will have similar local properties away from the sites of topology changes and texture seams.

If we "compress" this as you propose for the geometry shader approach, then for each quad we need:

- 2 faces, each containing:

  - face point (3 floats = 12 bytes)

    - vertex 1 travel (3 floats = 12 bytes)
    - vertex 2 travel (3 floats = 12 bytes)
  - face texture coordinate (2 floats = 8 bytes)

    - vertex 1 texture coordinate travel (2 floats = 8 bytes)
    - vertex 2 texture coordinate travel (2 floats = 8 bytes)

So that's **120 bytes per quad** of mesh. Seems... kind of heavy. Let's say we reduce the storage for all our travel offsets, assuming our triangles are small so we don't need the full range and precision of a 32-bit float to get from one side to the other. If we half their storage, that brings us down to **80 bytes per quad**. If we get really aggressive and quarter it (so only 256 distinct values possible), we're down to **60 bytes per quad**.

Now let's compare that to traditional indexed rendering:

- 4 vertices per quad, each shared between 4 quads, means 1 vertex per quad on average. Each vertex contains:

  - position (3 floats = 12 bytes)
  - texture coordinate (2 floats = 8 bytes)
  - normal (3 floats = 12 bytes)
- 6 indices per quad (6 shorts = 12 bytes)

For a total of **44 bytes per quad** of mesh.

So your "compression" strategy actually *increases* your upload bandwidth requirements by about 36%, even if we're maximally aggressive in compressing our local offsets. It also adds an extra programmable stage to the rendering pipeline, increasing our latency. And it costs you the use of the GPU's vertex cache, which can often save us from re-running the vertex shader on shared vertices, making this solution even more costly.

---

If instead you're dealing with attributes that are largely not shared between adjacent faces, then you can do this more simply using a constant buffer, and indexing into it with vertex ID in the vertex shader (divided by 3).

Per triangle, that's then:

- 3 unique vertices, each containing:

  - position (3 floats = 12 bytes)
  - texture coordinate (2 floats = 8 bytes)
- 1 entry in your constant buffer, containing:

  - face normal (3 floats = 12 bytes)
  - (other shared triangle attributes, as needed)

For a total of 72 bytes per triangle, not significantly more than the compressed version uses for the same precision. And we still don't need to add an extra pipeline stage or break the vertex cache to do it.

---

Moral of the story: check that it's really a problem before you attempt to "solve" it with something more complex.

Comment: The issue with that calculation is it assumes per vertex the normal and tex pt is the same from face to face.

Comment: Yep, this assumption is stated in the first sentence: "For simplicity, let's assume you're working with an endless grid of 2-triangle quads, with normals/texture coordinates shared at each vertex" - if this is not representative of the meshes you're dealing with, then you should be sure to include a description of those meshes in your question.